# What should i do change link color?

Tags: css

I am just trying to change a link color. Initially it will show red color, if it is visited then green and for mouse hover yellow. But it is showing green from the first. Where am i doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a.class1:link  { color: red;}
a.class1:visited { color: green;}
a.class1:hover { color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Down there is a link...
<br>
<span class="class1">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="class1">Google</a>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it because you have clicked the link before? That's what `visited` means. Inspect the element and see what pseudo-class it gets. Probably visited.

Comment: Change the url to a non visited site you will see it red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are targeting the `span`  and the `a` plus you already visited the `http://www.google.com`, so here is how :

#### Snippet

```css
a.class1:link {
  color: red;
}
a.class1:visited {
  color: green;
}
a.class1:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
This link will be red (because you -OP- didn't visit yet)
<span>
<a href="#randomlinkhere" target="_blank" class="class1">Google</a>
</span>

<hr />
This link will be green (because you -OP- already visited)
<span>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="class1">Google</a>
</span>
```